# Visual Studio Community Edition always has a * character in the title bar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I just installed VS Community Edition, all was great with one small annoyance, there is always a * character in the end of "Microsoft Visual Studio" title bar at the top. So the title bar changes from

```
XXX (Debug|Any CPU) - Microsoft Visual Studio
```

to

```
XXX (Debug|Any CPU) - Microsoft Visual Studio *
```

Here is the image [image: Star]

Why's that?

Comment: Would you mind taking a screenshot?

Comment: Ok, I just think this is obvious enough, so I didn't take one. Please wait for a few minutes as that adding a picture to a SO is quite some work, for me anyway.

Comment: Usually the star indicates that you have a file with unsaved changes.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have unsaved files. Even if I do, the star should be on the title bar of the file, not VS. Also even if I don't open projects, there is this *.

Comment: Perhaps something specific to your install, I just opened a project edited files and resaved all- don't see the star symbol in title bar

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that I have VS2012 installed before installing VS2013. So now I have two VS, VS2012 and VS2013. Could that be the reason?